# default to zsh interpreter in Mac Terminal?

Tags: zsh

How can I make sure .sh files are executed with the zshell interpreter from the Mac terminal without specifying the zsh prefix every time? The shell default is set to zshell already but a command to run a .sh file won't execute unless I prefix with zsh...

Comment: What does `echo $SHELL`  return? Is there a `"#!` at the start of the script file? If so, what executable does it point to?

Answer (score 1):

To change the shell to zsh: `chsh -s $(which zsh)` (zsh is probably the default shell already).

To run a .sh script without having to use `zsh` command:

1. prefix the script with a shebang line such as `#!/usr/bin/env zsh`.
2. make the script executable: `chmod +x <filename>`
3. run it as `./<filename>`